# Evaluation order in a for-loop initialization in C

Tags: c, for-loop, initialization

Consider this C-snippet:

```
int a;
int b;
for (a = 0, b = a + 1; a < N; a++)
    /* Something. */
```

Does the C specification clearly requires a compiler to keep the statements in the for-initializer in the order they appear?

I am specifically trying to avoid undefined behavior, if, for example, `a` was in an outer/global scope and the specification was not strict in this specific area.  In other words, I want to be sure that the example above has a clear definition for compilers, and not enter gray areas such as `a = ++a + b++;`.

Comment: Yes; see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: `a = ++a + b++;` is not a gray area, it is clearly undefined behaviour.

Comment: ..and considering that the OP had to ask, the above code is a grey area.  Why is it so awesomely difficult to write code that is immediately readable and understandable?

Comment: @martin-james The language allows such constructs.  I want to be sure of the behavior, since in the end, it is up to the compiler to ultimately materialize the intentions as executable code.

Comment: @MartinJames Having to ask does not make something a gray area. A beginner has to ask how to print "Hello World." I guess that makes all code a gray area then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specially in the for-initializer, the expression in left of comma operator (`a = 0`) will be evaluated first, then the right (`b = a + 1`) will be evaluated.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.17 Comma operator

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point after its evaluation. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its
>   type and value.

Comment: You might want to explain that a comma is not always a comma operator, like in `f(a = 0, b = a + 1);`.